# Installing electrical box in 2x4

Tags: electrical, wood, code-compliance, safety

I'm designing a custom headboard for our bed and I want to install electrical into the cubbies I am making in the headboard (primarily for cell phone charging). In my current design, the electrical box would be installed into a cut out 2x4.

I've attached two sketchup models for reference. My primary question is this: **Are there any U.S. electrical codes or even best practices I need to be aware of in regards to where and into what material I can install an electrical box?** The only thing I could find was that a box can protrude through up to 1/2" of drywall, so I'm wondering if that means that attempting to protrude through a larger (flammable) piece of material like this is against code. If you have any other related advice/caution about running electrical into furniture, that would be welcomed as well. Thanks!

EDIT: In my design, this 2x4 could be changed to a different material, but initially I was trying to keep the structure to 2x4s and plywood for simplicity. I could switch to a thinner material if that would help me to be in compliance.

[image: Front], [image: Side]

Comment: I assume the headboard is firmly mounted to the wall and not easily moved. If not, you may have a problem meeting code with the cabling to the box.

Comment: @bib while that wasn't my main question, it was one of my questions. I was l planning on having a 10' wired cord (at least 14 gauge) with a strain relief entering the headboard and then possibly connecting to a surge strip for additional protectio. It will be firmly mounted, but I do want to design it to be moved in the future if necessary. I was also considering some kind of [panel mounting plug](https://guideimg.alibaba.com/images/shop/80/10/09/0/5-pcs-panel-mounting-male-power-supply-plug-10a-ac-250v_2002390.jpg) on the bottom but was worried about having no strain relief

Comment: If you want it potentially moveable, I would use armored cable, an MC compatible plug, and a handibox with appropriate connectors instead of a plastic J box. It would, in effect, be a non-UL device rather than part of the permanent wiring. Also, the box it plugs into must be accessible.

Comment: I am familiar with most household electrical wiring and practices but I am drawing a blank on an MC compatible plug. Could you provide a link? Thanks

Comment: One example: https://vetco.net/products/armored-cable-mc-cable-male-ac-plug-nema-5-15p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A box can penetrate any material, not just 1/2" drywall.

For non-flammable surfaces you can have the box set back up to 1/4". Ultimately though you want to be flush with the surface.

For flammable surfaces you must be flush with the finished surface.

This is borrowed from a post by @tester101:

> **ARTICLE 314**
>
> **Outlet, Device, Pull, and Junction Boxes;
> Conduit Bodies; Fittings; and Handhole Enclosures**
>
> **314.20 In Wall or Ceiling.** In walls or ceilings with a surface of concrete, tile, gypsum, plaster, or other noncombustible material,
> boxes employing a ﬂush-type cover or faceplate shall be installed so
> that the front edge of the box, plaster ring, extension ring, or
> listed extender will not be set back of the ﬁnished surface more than
> 6 mm (1⁄4 in.). In walls and ceilings constructed of wood or other
> combustible surface material, boxes, plaster rings, extension rings,
> or listed extenders shall be ﬂush with the ﬁnished surface or project
> therefrom.

This might also be relevant.

> **406.4 Receptacle Mounting.** Receptacles shall be mounted in boxes or assemblies designed for the purpose, and such boxes or assemblies
> shall be securely fastened in place unless otherwise permitted
> elsewhere in this Code.
>
> **(A) Boxes That Are Set Back.** Receptacles mounted in boxes that are set back from the finished surface as permitted in 314.20 shall be
> installed such that the mounting yoke or strap of the receptacle is
> held rigidly at the finished surface.